# Create provider for use in angular .config()

Tags: angularjs, angular-providers

I am trying to create a provider for use in the .config(), but do not know where I am going wrong, since it is the first time I create a provider ..

Actually want to return the result of the CacheFactory provider .. have a factory already working but as in the config does not accept factory, I have this problem.

```
.factory('_CONFIG', ['$cacheFactory', function($cacheFactory) {
    return $cacheFactory('config_global');
}])

.provider('__CONFIG', function($cacheFactory) {
    var _cache = $cacheFactory('config_global');
    return {
        $get: function(key) {
            return _cache.get(key);
        }
    };
});
```

I want to use here:

```
.config(['$mdThemingProvider', function ($mdThemingProvider, __CONFIGProvider) {
    'use strict';

    var themes = __CONFIGProvider.get('config');

    if(themes.themes_dark) {
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .dark()
            .primaryPalette('blue', {
                'hue-1'   : '700',
                'hue-2'   : '600',
                'hue-3'   : '500'
            })
            .accentPalette('pink');
    }
    else {
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
            .primaryPalette('blue', {
                'hue-1'   : '700',
                'hue-2'   : '600',
                'hue-3'   : '500'
            })
            .accentPalette('pink');
    }

}])
```

NEW PLUNKER: http://plnkr.co/edit/RVK8EwoyOQNka5E84jSg?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('app',[
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngMaterial'
])

.provider('__CONFIG', function() {

    var config = this;

    //Config manipulations
    (function(){
    config.themeselect = [
        {name: 'Blue', value: 'blue'},
        {name: 'Light Blue', value: 'light-blue'},
        {name: 'Indigo', value: 'indigo'},
        {name: 'Pink', value: 'pink'},
        {name: 'Teal', value: 'teal'},
        {name: 'Lime', value: 'lime'},
    ];

    config.themes_primary = 'indigo';
    config.themes_accent = 'pink';  
    })()


    return {
      //This will be seen by the config function
      primary:function(){return config.themes_primary;},
      accent:function(){return config.themes_accent;},
        //Get is being seen by controllers
        $get: function(){
          return {
            primary: function(){
              return config.themes_primary;
            },
            accent: function(){
              return config.themes_accent;
            },
            themeselect:config.themeselect
          }
    }
  };
})

.controller('Themes', function(__CONFIG){
  var vm = this;
  vm.themeselect = __CONFIG.themeselect;

})



.config(['$mdThemingProvider','__CONFIGProvider', function ($mdThemingProvider, __CONFIGProvider) {
    'use strict';

    var primary = __CONFIGProvider.primary(),
        accent = __CONFIGProvider.accent();

        console.log(primary);

    $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
        .primaryPalette(primary)
        .accentPalette(accent);

    $mdThemingProvider.alwaysWatchTheme(true);

}])
```

```
<script data-require="angular.js@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-animate.js" data-semver="1.4.3" data-require="angular-animate@1.4.3"></script>
<script data-require="angular-aria@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.1/angular-material.min.js" data-semver="0.10.1" data-require="angular-material@*"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

```
<div layout="column" layout-fill>

<md-toolbar class="md-primary">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools admin-toolbar-tools" ng-click="openMenu()" tabIndex="-1">

        <div layout="row" flex class="fill-height">
            <h2 class="md-title">Themes</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

</md-toolbar>
<md-content ng-controller="Themes as vm" layout-padding>



  <md-input-container class="md-accent">
        <label>Selecione o Tema Primário</label>
        <md-select name="themes_primary" ng-model="themes_primary" placeholder="Selecione o Tema Primário" class="md-accent">
            <md-option ng-repeat="theme in vm.themeselect" value="{{theme.value}}" class="md-accent" md-theme-watch>{{theme.name}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container class="md-accent">
        <label>Selecione o Tema Primário</label>
        <md-select name="themes_accent" ng-model="themes_accent" placeholder="Selecione o Tema Accent" class="md-accent">
            <md-option ng-repeat="theme in vm.themeselect" value="{{theme.value}}" class="md-accent" md-theme-watch>{{theme.name}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-button class="md-raised md-accent">Theme Apply</md-button>
    <md-button class="md-raised">CANCEL</md-button>




</md-content>
</div>
```

Comment: Show! But, as dynamically I change the values of primary and accent fields?

Comment: I mean, complete with variables for example selects

Comment: You can actually select the accent and primary, and only implementation of applying it is required now.. its there.. did i miss something?

Comment: this code, enter in provider? var $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

Comment: You can always save vars in $rootScope.. and if so you can inject it to the config and other controllers... but, you created a provider for that. so why do you need a $rootScope for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91020/discussion-between-marco-riesco-and-lior-ben-aharon).

Answer (score 0):

```
    .config([
    '$mdThemingProvider',
    /*!~~!!!!You missed Me!!!!~~!*/
    '__CONFIGProvider',//<-------------------- 
function ($mdThemingProvider, __CONFIGProvider)
```

2. Are both code files a part of the same module? (angular.module...) if not, check if the module of the provider is listed in the dep injection of the config module..
3. Check if the provider appears before or after the config file at the index file.

Comment: It did not work, I believe it is the provider of the code you have something wrong, because back an error saying that the provider is wrong.

Comment: Listen, i'm more then sure that u're string missing of the parameter doesn't let the function get the parameter __CONFIGProvider. Add the "__CONFIGProvider" before the function in the array..

Comment: Can you create a plnkr of this project? Because it seems fine and i assume there is something else going on.. and i need to see the big picture..